# Confirm command by pressing same key that invoked it

Tags: key-bindings

I have `<f5>` bound to `projectile-run-project`. When pressing `<f5>`, the minibuffer displays the command to run and you need to press `RET` to confirm it.

How can I add the behavior that when `<f5>` is pressed again, it acts as a `RET` to confirm and execute the command?

UPDATE:
my working projectile config after the answer from @Tobias

```
(use-package projectile
  :init (setq
         projectile-project-search-path '("c:/repo") ;; todo make variable and declare it in paths
         projectile-enable-caching t
         projectile-completion-system 'helm
         projectile-indexing-method 'native)
         (add-hook 'ibuffer-hook
             (lambda ()
                 (ibuffer-projectile-set-filter-groups)
                 (unless (eq ibuffer-sorting-mode 'alphabetic)
                     (ibuffer-do-sort-by-alphabetic))))
  ;; projectile-globally-ignored-file-suffixes
  ;; (append '("S" "elf" "o") projectile-globally-ignored-file-suffixes))

  :bind-keymap
  ("C-c p" . projectile-command-map)

  :bind
  ("<f5>" . projectile-run-project)

  :config (projectile-mode +1))

(defun my-read-shell-command-key-wrapper (oldfun &rest args)
  "Wrapper for `projectile-run-project' that temporarily adds <f5> to the keymap."
  (let ((minibuffer-local-shell-command-map (copy-sequence minibuffer-local-shell-command-map)))
    (define-key minibuffer-local-shell-command-map (kbd "<f5>") (kbd "RET"))
    (apply oldfun args)))

(advice-add 'projectile-run-project :around #'my-read-shell-command-key-wrapper)
```

Comment: From the description of the elisp tag: "DO NOT USE it for questions about customization or how to write an application."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working horse of `projectile-run-project` is [`projectile--run-project-cmd`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/341150c0e77c63075f53e346dae87a4c60ea3b5b/projectile.el#L3889) which uses indirectly [`read-shell-command`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/341150c0e77c63075f53e346dae87a4c60ea3b5b/projectile.el#L3847).

I don't have `projectile` but I demonstrate here how you can implement the binding of <kbd>f5</kbd> with a simple example that works for me in Emacs 26.3. You can just replace `example-shell-command` in the `advice-add` with `projectile-run-project`. Naturally, in your usecase you do not need the definition of `example-shell-command` anymore.

```el
(defun my-read-shell-command-key-wrapper (oldfun &rest args)
  "Wrapper for `projectile-run-project' that temporarily adds <f5> to the keymap."
  (let ((minibuffer-local-shell-command-map (copy-sequence minibuffer-local-shell-command-map)))
    (define-key minibuffer-local-shell-command-map (kbd "<f5>") (kbd "RET"))
    (apply oldfun args)))

(defun example-shell-command ()
  "Example: Read and call shell command."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (read-shell-command "Shell command:")))

(advice-add 'example-shell-command :around #'my-read-shell-command-key-wrapper)
```

Comment: Could it be you made a little mistake somewhere? Pressing `<f5>` the first time throws me a message: `let: Symbol’s function definition is void: copy-list` I've updated OP with my config for projectile. Apperently I'm running 26.2. But can update to 26.3 if needed (waiting for stable 27).

Comment: changing `copy-list` to `copy-sequence` did the trick. Thanks for your example! EDIT: apperently `cl-copy-list` also works

Comment: @Swedgin I am sorry about that . That was the old-fashioned `copy-list` from `cl.el`. `cl-copy-list` from `cl-lib.el` would be better. But, the C-implemented `copy-sequence` also works very fine here. So I've replaced `copy-list` with `copy-sequence`. Thanks for the notice.